# React component: how to make sure component is below the others

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

Currently, my component with children looks like this:
[image: 1]
My component's code:

```
const container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  width: max-content;
`
```

I want to add components to the bottom of it like this:
[image: 2]

How do I do so?

Comment: codesandbox link please

Comment: @AmanSadhwani ive added my component code, which has a width of max-content, but after the 3rd child component, i always want it to be on the 2nd row

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is by using `display: grid` in your CSS and then setting your `grid-template-columns` and `grid-column` as needed

Comment: do you have an example of this?

Comment: i do still want flex if that makes sense

Comment: @timmy with `display: flex`, you can use `flex-wrap: wrap;` which will make your items inside the main div more dynamic. However, this only makes it dynamic and it doesn't let you define the width for each component inside of it like `grid-template-column` does in `display: grid`. You will have to specify those yourself.